# How to append one value to every tuple within a list?

Tags: python, list, append, tuples, sublist

How to append 1 value to every tuple within a list?

```
 tuple_list = [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
 value = 111


 Desired_List = [(111,'a','b'),(111,'c','d'),(111,'e','f')]
```

I've tried the following:

```
   for x in tuple_list:
        x.append(111)

   for x in tuple_list:
        x + '111'
```

I prefer sublists over tuples, so is there anyway to change the tuples to sublists as well?

Notes: 
It actually doesn't matter whether the 111 is in the first index or the last index of the tuple.

Comment: tuples are immutable, so you cannot append things to them. You can only create new tuples.

Comment: You can concatenate tuples, though, so "appending" 111 could be done with `x += (111,)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to do both of the things you're looking to do.

To prefix:

```
desired_list = [[value]+list(tup) for tup in tuple_list]
```

To suffix:

```
desired_list = [list(tup)+[value] for tup in tuple_list]
```

The `list()` call transforms each tuple into a list, and adding another list which contains only `value` adds that value to each list once it has been created.

Comment: I think this solution is slightly off-mark since the OP wanted a list of tuples, not a list of lists. Simple fix using the provided solution is as follows: `desired_list = [tuple(list(tup)+[value]) for tup in tuple_list]`

Comment: To get the correct list of tuples solution, you can avoid multiple casts by doing `desired_list = [(value,)+v for v in tuple_list]`

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a `map` with lambda-function for this:

```
new_list = map(lambda x: [111] + list(x), tuple_list)
```

Comment: List comprehensions are considered more Pythonic than `map`+`lambda`.

Comment: Isn't map + lambda faster tho?

Comment: @Amber No one knows what "pythonic" means any more. This is just another alternative, which could be faster, could be slower, but a viable solution... Some people love lambdas and maps and filters... I love list comprehensions and generators, but it has nothing to do with the validity of the answer :)

Comment: "pythonic"? Isn't it time that phrase was retired? The list comp is generally easier to understand in my view, but the lambda is a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: @Chris I doubt there is any difference. Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`.

```
>>> tuple_list = [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
>>> map(list, tuple_list)
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

Or a list comprehension.

```
>>> [list(elem) for elem in tuple_list]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

Since your desired output is a list of tuples, you can do.

```
>>> [(111,) + elem for elem in tuple_list]
[(111, 'a', 'b'), (111, 'c', 'd'), (111, 'e', 'f')]
```